# Android studio crashed. Any project doesnt work and it has red lines

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The problem began, when I was building the gradle for my phone, that was connected by usb. I switched off my telephone when the gradle was building. After that, all lines became red. Any of android projects crashes. Every line is red. I tried to clean project, to rebuild it, but nothing helps. APK, JDK etc are  installed. Gradle is synchronized several times. Android studio builds APK and gradle finishes succeesfully, but lines are still red. Is there any suggestions to solve this problem? Look at the picture for better understanding

[image]

Comment: may be android sdk not installed successfully.check build tool.

Comment: Clean your project and check interent is working or not.It need to synchronise with gradle.

Comment: is this still appear when you create new project?

Comment: backup your project and reinstall android sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select invalidate cache / restart under file menu. It happened to me once and i did the exact same thing and it worked for me.

or

Manually delete all files of .grade folder, it's placed in c://Users/your user name/.gradle then clean and rebuild the gradle.

I hope you'll get your problem solved using any of these two methods. GOOD LUCK!!

Comment: Thank you very much! invalidate cache / restart - helped me

Answer (score 1):

1. Clean project
2. Rebuild project
3. **Sync Gradle**

if doesn't work try to check build tool

or -
  clean out the system caches:

On the main menu, choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart. The Invalidate Caches message appears informing you that the caches will be invalidated and rebuilt on the next start. Use buttons in the dialog to invalidate caches, restart IntelliJ IDEA or both.

**Gradle cache**

Gradle cache locates at

On Windows: %USER_HOME%.gradle/caches
On Mac/Unix: $HOME/.gradle/caches/
You can browse to these directory and manually delete it or run